# Erro type mismatch: cannot convert from String to String[] - Como posso corrigir?

Tags: java, string, matriz

Ao tentar receber valor através de um `JOptionPane` em uma matriz, mas dá esse erro:

```
type mismatch: cannot convert from String to String[]
```

Como posso corrigir?

Segue meu código fonte abaixo:

```
package br.deivsoft.estudo.modelo;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class TestaAnalistas {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Analistas analist = new Analistas();

        analist.nome = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite seu nome: ");
        analist.matricula = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite sua matricula: ");
        analist.equipe = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite sua equipe: ");


        analist.demandas = new String[3][4];

        for (int i = 0; i < analist.demandas.length; i++) {
            analist.demandas[i] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite o nome: ");
            for (int j = 0; j < analist.demandas[i].length; j++) {
                analist.demandas[i][j] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite a demanda: ");
            }
        }

        analist.exibirDadosAnalistas();

    }

}
```

```
package br.deivsoft.estudo.modelo;

public class Analistas {

    String nome;
    String matricula;
    String equipe;
    String[][] demandas;




    void exibirDadosAnalistas() {

        System.out.println("Nome: "+nome);
        System.out.println("Matricula: "+matricula);
        System.out.println("Equipe: "+equipe);

        for (int i = 0; i < demandas.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Analista: "+demandas[i]);
            for (int j = 0; j < demandas[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.println("Demanda: "+demandas[i][j]);
            }
        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 4):

O seu erro está aqui:

```
analist.demandas[i] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite o nome: ");
```

`demandas[i]` é uma linha da matriz com várias strings. Não dá para se colocar uma única string lá.

O seu problema é mais profundo, a sua modelagem está bastante errada. Você definiu que um `Analistas` é uma pessoa com `nome`, `matricula` e `equipe`. Até aqui tudo bem, mas que cada `Analistas` tem uma matriz bidimensional de demandas onde as linhas também são analistas e as células da matriz são as demandas propriamente ditas.

Acho que o que você queria era criar um array de analistas e cada analista com o seu array de demandas. Isso faria bem mais sentido:

```
package br.deivsoft.estudo.modelo;

public class Analista {

    private String nome;
    private String matricula;
    private String equipe;
    private String[] demandas;

    public Analista(String nome, String matricula, String equipe, String[] demandas) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.nome = matricula;
        this.nome = equipe;
        this.nome = demandas;
    }

    public void exibirDados() {
        System.out.println("Nome: " + nome);
        System.out.println("Matricula: " + matricula);
        System.out.println("Equipe: " + equipe);

        for (int i = 0; i < demandas.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Demanda: " + demandas[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

```
package br.deivsoft.estudo.modelo;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class TestaAnalistas {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Analista[] analistas = new Analista[3];

        for (int i = 0; i < analistas.length; i++) {
            String nome = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite seu nome:");
            String matricula = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite sua matricula:");
            String nome = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite sua equipe:");
            String[] demandas = new String[4];

            for (int j = 0; j < demandas; j++) {
                demandas[j] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite a demanda: ");
            }
            analistas[i] = new Analista(nome, matricula, nome, demandas);
        }

        for (Analista a : analistas) {
            a.exibirDados();
        }
    }
}
```

E por fim algumas recomendações:

- Nunca omita os modificadores `public` ou `private` a menos que você tenha certeza absoluta que quer visibilidade de pacote.
- Nomes de classes em geral são no singular porque cada instância dela representa um único objeto.
- Evite redundância no nome. Em uma classe chamada `Analista`, o nome do método pode ser apenas `exibirDados`, vez que pelo contexto, sabe-se que trata-se dos dados do `Analista`. Logo, o nome `exibirDadosAnalistas` é redundante.
- Se você tem vários analistas, então vai usar um array de analistas. Se cada analista tem várias demandas, então terá um array com as demandas dentro de cada analista. Criar uma matriz de demandas de todos os analistas vai ser algo bem mais difícil, feio e confuso e tem bem menos chances de dar certo.
- Não acesse campos de objetos de outras classes nunca (exceto quando uma estiver dentro da outra, o que não é o seu caso). Isso é considerado uma péssima prática de programação em Java.